# Racing (race condition) issue of queue in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, queue, race-condition

Thanks to Michael's and Adam's comments I made some changes here. 
Suppose I build a special linked queue with max length N.

```
class QueueItem
{
  int id; //object identity
  double data; //object priority 
}

class MyQueue
{
  private:
    list<QueueItem> rec;
    std::mutex mymutex;
  public:
    LinkArray(){};
    ~LinkArray(){};
    int insert(int id, double d)
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mymutex);
      list<QueueItem>::iterator iter=rec.begin();
      QueueItem temp;
      temp.id = id;
      temp.data = d;
      int count=0;
      for (iter;iter!=rec.end();iter++)
      {
        if (iter->data<d)
        {
          rec.insert(iter,temp);
          return count;
        }
        count++;
      }
      rec.push_back(temp);
      return count;
    }
    void pop(void)
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mymutex);
      rec.pop_back();
    }
    int getLength(void)
    {
      return rec.size();
    }

};
```

The rule is: all the items in the queue always have the highest priority and they are sorted. For example for N=4, the priority in the queue is (100,99,98,97). When priority 101 enqueue, the queue becomes (101,100,99,98). If 1 enqueue, then the queue doesn't change.

Now, if I use `<thread>` in C++11 to compute the priority for different object in different threads and then enqueue them, how can I avoid race condition?

My code is like:

```
 ....
 int N = 4; //queue length
 int pnum=4;//thread number
 MyQueue* queue = new MyQueue(8);
 vector<thread> threads;
 std::mutex mymux;
 int totalItem = 16;
 int itemIds[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
 double itemPriority[] = {9,10,3,11,2,12,5,6,7,8,1,15,14,4,13,16};
 int itemperthread = totalItem/pnum;
 for (int p=0; p<pnum;p++)
 {
    threads.push_back(thread([&](int p, MyQueue* queue ){
       for (int i=p*itemperthread; i<(p+1)*itemperthread; i++)
       { 
         int id = itemIds[i];
         int priority = itemPriority[i];
       }
       mymux.lock();
       queue->insert(id,priority); //enqueue
       if (queue->getLength()>N)
         queue->pop();
       mymux.unlock();
    },p, queue));
 }
 for (auto& thread : threads){
   thread.join();
 }
```

I tried use a mutex to lock the queue (or even define a mutex in Queue class and use it in Queue::insert method). But everytime I run this, the result of queue is different. I am pretty sure the computation of priority is correct.

The expected *queue* after run this part of program will be [16,15,14,13]. But the result can be different every time I run it.

Any idea to avoid this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I think you'd at least have to show use the `Queue::insert()` function.  It might be nice to also show use some examples of incorrect results and what you expected instead of the incorrect results.

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly be a snippet from a working program.  In the lambda, `queue` is a pointer to a `Queue`, and should have no member functions on it (since pointers are built-in types), but this code calls `queue.insert(...)`.  (`queue->insert(...)` would make more sense.)  Since you're dealing with a subtle issue that is surprising you, I think we need all the relevant code (including, as Michael Burr mentions, the `insert` member fn).  Can you provide a minimal, compilable piece of code that demonstrates the issue and that other people could use to confirm your findings?

Comment: Problem is not in the code you're showing us. Stylistically, it's weird to capture some things in a lambda and pass arguments to the `std::thread` constructor - you should do one or the other.

Comment: Can you give an example for an incorrect result?

Comment: Where is mymutex coming from? As Adam H. Peterson asked: can you provide a minimal, compiling piece of code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: mymutex is defined in the Queue class.

Comment: I suspect the problem arises from if (queue->getLength()>N) queue->pop(); - your snippet does not show the definition of N, however if it is smaller than 16 (totalItem), your solution is not deterministic: the first thread to push the Nth item will pop something off the queue - but which thread that is and what items have already been pushed on at that point - and thus, what it pops - will depend on the order in which threads got scheduled, which is random; and thus what is left on the queue when all work is complete will be random.

Comment: Thanks moonshadow , that make a lot of sense. N is always less than totalItem size (I set 4 here as an example).